# is there anyway to increase an output voltage 100V DC to 110V DC using caps the source available is 110 V RMS?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, capacitor, switches, power-electronics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGYXAD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you ever heard of p-p voltage vs. RMS volts? Look up those terms and you will find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With 110 V RMS sine, the peaks are 156 V.  Minus two diode drops, that should give you peaks of 154 V out of the full wave bridge.

With sufficient capacitance, you should definitely be able to get 100 V DC average out, assuming the rest of the system can handle whatever current your load takes at 100 V.

Comment: thats true but the thing is i have separately excited motor 110 V DC and i need exactly 110 V on the field coil and i want to keep them constant using caps to gurante that the field voltage won't drop untill the armature decays to zero

Answer (score 1):

If the source is 110 VAC RMS, then it has peaks of ~1.41 * 110 V, rectified and smoothed with some bulk capacitance that would give you 155.1 VDC less a diode drop.